# Android Asynk Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

is a good practice to have an Asynk task with a loop like this inside?

```
while (true) { 
check queue and request API
```

Because i need to wait for my Activities and service needs to comunicate with the APi.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the "queue" is a Java queue, perhaps a `LinkedBlockingQueue`. If so, that queue is unnecessary, as `AsyncTask` has a queue to go along with its thread pool.

So, the question is: what triggers things to go in the queue?

If the trigger is a user event (e.g., menu choice, button push), just have it launch an `AsyncTask`, or have it have a `Service` launch an `AsyncTask`. That work will be queued up by the `AsyncTask` system.

If the trigger is the passage of time (e.g., we want to check an external server every 10 minutes), I would use `AlarmManager` and consider switching from `AsyncTask` and a `Service` to using an `IntentService`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a priority queue in order to select first the important calls to the API.

My program have two services:

- One calls the API when a message is added to the queue. The call to the api is made by an Asinc Task in this way:

  ```
  messages.add(request);  
  new DownloadApiTask().execute();
  ```
- The other service is updating the local database. For that, i have a loop in which i call the first service in order to get data from the API. The basic structure is:

  `while i`have data to updload

  mFirstService.putMessage(request).

Fine, the problem is i have a rejected Execution Exception every X calls, I think it can be because i invoke the asinc task every time i take a message.

For that, i was thinking in force to the asinck task to check the queue instead executing it.

I hope you can understand my problem.

Thanks